# How to draw polynom division?

Tags: polynom

I want to draw  this scheme, but I do not know how to start. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Do you need to set it up exactly like that, or could you use the [`polynom`](http://ctan.org/pkg/polynom) package? See [the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/polynom) and the demofile, [polydemo.pdf](http://texdoc.net/pkg/polydemo).

Comment: Following up Andrew's comment: Why don't you just change the title to something related to "polynom division", provide some context, and mention what you have already tried?

Comment: Why do you want to use `TikZ` to typeset a polynomial division problem?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed what you have tried so far in the way of a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).  While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Is (local) layout important?

Typesetting polynom division can easy be done with the `polynom` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Style A:}\par % this is the default
\polylongdiv[style=A]{6x^3-2x^2+x+3}{x^2-x+1}

\textbf{Style B:}\par
\polylongdiv[style=B]{6x^3-2x^2+x+3}{x^2-x+1}

\textbf{Style C:}\par
\polylongdiv[style=C]{6x^3-2x^2+x+3}{x^2-x+1}

\textbf{Style D:}\par
\polylongdiv[style=D]{6x^3-2x^2+x+3}{x^2-x+1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm afraid I didn't try to change layout (yet), but that will be another question...

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed @torbjorn-t 's comment...  makes my answer a duplicate.  I'll let it be for sake of the MWE?

Comment: If you can, please write a code which out put like my picture.

Comment: @minthao_2011 `polynom` can't create output exactly like your picture. It has three ways of representing polynomial division, examples of which you can see in polydemo.pdf, that I linked to in my comment to your question.

Comment: @TomDierckx I took the liberty of expanding your example a little, and adding an image, hope that's OK.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: of course that's ok...  It means a valuable addition.

Comment: Style D in `polynom` package is what you need. `\polylongdiv[style=D]{6x^3-2x^2+x+3}{x^2-x+1}`

Comment: Is there a way to make the polynom package accept variable labels other than x? If I try to typeset a polynomial long division using the variable T or t using that package, the output is screwed up, but it turns into something okay when I use x. I really wish this package were more flexible about accepting different labels for the variable.

Comment: @KCd Yes. You can use `\polyset{vars=XYZT}` to use X, Y, Z, and T as variables. But I believe that each polynomial should use only one of those variables.

Answer (score 28):

Since the structure lends itself to an `array`, here is such an elementary implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\dropsign}[1]{\smash{\llap{\raisebox{-.5\normalbaselineskip}{$#1$\hspace{2\arraycolsep}}}}}%
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{r|r}
    \dropsign{-} 6x^3 - 2x^2 + \phantom{6}x + 3 & x^2 - \phantom{6}x + 1 \\ \cline{2-2}
    6x^3 - 6x^2 + 6x \phantom{{}+3} & 6x + 4 \\ \cline{1-1} \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+\jot]
    \dropsign{-} 4x^2 - 5x + 3 \\
                 4x^2 - 4x + 4 \\ \cline{1-1} \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+\jot]
                      -  x - 1
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

For fun with TikZ.

Explanation: `\phantom` is used to vertically align `x`, `x^2`, `x^3`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.5]
\def\c{2}
\draw[blue,thick] 
(0,.5)--+(-90:5)
(0,-.5)--+(0:2)
(0,-1.5)--+(180:3)
(0,-3.5)--+(180:2);

\path[left]
(0,0)     node{$6x^3-2x^2+\phantom{6}x+3$}
++(-90:1) node{$6x^3-6x^2+6x\phantom{{}+3}$}
++(-90:1) node{$4x^2-5x+3$}
++(-90:1) node{$4x^2-4x+4$}
++(-90:1) node{$-x-1$};

\path[left,magenta]
(0,-.5)  +(180:.2) node{$-$\phantom{$6x^3-2x^2+\phantom{6}x+3$}}
(0,-2.5) +(180:.2) node{$-$\phantom{$4x^2-5x+3$}};

\path[left]
(\c,0)   node{$x^2-\phantom{6}x+1$}
+(-90:1) node{$6x+4$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution, hard to reuse without minimim explanations (eq , node{$6x^3-2x^2+\phantom{6}x+3$} and ++(-90:1) node{$6x^3-6x^2+6x\phantom{{}+3}$}.

Comment: @pzorba75 I added some explanation of `\phantom`. Just tell me if you need more explain

Comment: It is OK to me now, just a bit long to enter but the division looks rigth.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question. Now, you can use `tabularray`

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={rrrrrrrr|rrrrr},
            cells={mode=dmath},
            colsep = .5mm } 
        \SetCell[r=2]{fg=red}- 
        & 6x^3 & - & 2x^2 & + & x & + & 3 & x^2 & - & x & + & 1 \\
\SetHline{9-13}{blue,0.5pt}
& 6x^3 & - & 6x^2 & + & 6x &  &  &  &  & 6x & + & 4 \\
\SetHline{2-8}{blue,0.5pt}
        %or \cline{2-8}
        \SetCell[r=2,c=3]{fg=red}-
&  &  & 4x^2 & - & 5x & + & 3 &  &  &  &  &  \\
&  &  & 4x^2 & - & 4x & + & 4 &  &  &  &  &  \\
        \SetHline{4-8}{blue,0.5pt}
        %\cline{4-8}
        &  &  &  & - & x & - & 1 &  &  &  &  &  \\
    \end{tblr}  
\end{document}
```

[image]