# How to typeset and annotate a polynomial long division

Tags: math-mode, polynom

I need to type a paper for a teacher, who hasn't seen the European division method, so that she could possibly use it in her curriculum.

I need something to look like this

```
x^2+4x+4       Box(x+2) 
-(x^2 + 2x)
----------------
2x+4 
-(2x + 4)
-----------------
0
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: I am not sure what the `Box(x+2)` means.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for not being clear. I want an actual box for x+2.

Comment: “European division” is unknown to me. I guess you meant http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division

Comment: Great picture IMHO: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Beispiel_Polynomdivision.png

Comment: Did you perchance mix up the words "European" and "Euclidean"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one way to do this:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `booktabs` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs) was used to provide flexible horizontal rules.
- The `\Ph` macro uses `\hphantom{)}` to insert a horizontal space equivalent to the closing bracket to get things all aligned.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand*{\Ph}{\hphantom{)}}%
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{r@{} r@{} r r}
  x^2 &{}+4x\Ph&{}+4\Ph       &\fbox{$(x+2)$} \\
-(x^2 &{}+ 2x) &\\
\cmidrule{1-2}
      & 2x\Ph &{}+4\Ph\\
      &-(2x\Ph &{}+4) \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
      & &0\Ph
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I get an actual box for the x+2? I really appreciate your help. My gratitude.

Comment: @Person: Use `\boxed{($x+2$)} ` with `amsmath` loaded.

Comment: @HarishKumar: I was not aware of `\boxed`, but that seems to force the text inside the box to be in `\text` mode somehow even with `$ $`, so used `\fbox` instead.

Comment: @PeterGrill: `\boxed` is defined by `amsmath` for `mathmode`. There is a similar `\Aboxed` in `mathtools`. If you use `\boxed{(x+2)}`, then it will be in `mathmode`. Don't use `$`.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Thanks. I am familiar with `\Aboxed` form my very first question posted on TeX.SE. But, am surprised that `\boxed{$(x+2)$}` compiled with `x` in text mode -- seems like a bug?

Answer (score 4):

Try looking at the package `polynom.sty` ([CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/polynom), [TeXdoc](http://texdoc.net/show.php?pkg=polynom)). It can even do the division for you.

Comment: For an example, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79222/586