# Long Division of Polynomials in LyX

Tags: lyx, packages, polynom

I look here for a way to show a long division of polynomials, and I read here about `polynom.sty`, but my question is if there is a way that I can write the whole division and not just give two polynomials as input.

i.e. I'm looking for a way to **write** a long division of polynomials.

If you have any suggestions I'd like to read!!

P.S. I'm using LyX.

Comment: If you're OK with writing it in ERTs you could look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82027/ or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79254/

Comment: Thank you @TorbjørnT. but I look for I way to write it by **myself**. At the first link the problem is that it's not clear... (it little it complicated...).  

There is no simpler way?

Comment: Both of those solutions use an `array`, so you could of course create an `array` via the LyX GUI, i.e. Insert --> Math --> Array environment.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you! but How I made the lines? This is what I look for: A way to write the long division at the array.
But how can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Hm. From a quick glance at LyX, there doesn't seem to be a way of adding a `\cline` in an `array` via the GUI. You can achieve the same effect in a normal `tabular`, but I didn't immediately see a way with `array`. Have to look at this later, don't really have time right now.

Comment: Take your time @TorbjørnT.! :-) I'll be glad if later you will explain me how to do it... Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I know it`s not the nicest way to do this, but here we go...

(I tried some time ago to find a nicer way and failed. I give you my improvised result)

Just enter the polynomials into a regular table, and use separating lines for the top and side. In LyX it looks like this:

[image: long division in lyx]

and after compilation it looks like this:

[image: long division in pdf]

Answer (score 3):

This might help you get started, if you don't mind doing the algebra yourself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xspace,xcolor}
\usepackage[display]{texpower}
\usepackage[screen,nopanel]{pdfscreen}

\margins{0.25in}{0.25in}{0.25in}{0.25in}
\screensize{4.5in}{6in}
\backgroundcolor{lightgray}

\newcommand{\ldsym}{$\left.\mathstrut\right)$}% unbalanced )
\newlength{\ldwidth}

\newcommand{\longdivide}[2]% #1 = denominator, #2 = numerator
{\settowidth{\ldwidth}{\ldsym}
$#1\,\raisebox{1.5pt}{\ldsym}\hspace*{-.65\ldwidth}\overline{
\mathstrut\hspace*{.35\ldwidth}\ #2}$}

\begin{document}
\stepwise{
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{r}
\bstep[\value{step}=1]{$7x$}\bstep[\value{step}=4]{$\strut+8$}\\
\longdivide{x^{2}-4x+1}{7x^{3}-20x^{2}-25x+8}\\
\bstep[\value{step}=2]{\underline{$7x^3-28x^2+7x$}}\hphantom{$\strut+8$}\\
\bstep[\value{step}=3]{$8x^2-32x+8$}\\
\bstep[\value{step}=5]{$8x^2-32x+8$}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: slide]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, there is no way to use `\cline` in an `array` environment via the LyX GUI. Therefore, to use the GUI to create the table-like structure, one has to use a `tabular`: Insert --> Table. It is not an ideal solution, as each cell has to be placed in (inline) math mode. The code below is a `.lyx` file with an example, copy the code into a text editor and save the file as `something.lyx`.

Things to note:

- I don't know if this is the kind of layout you'd like.
- The lines are added via the table toolbar, just select the cells you want underlined, and click the appropriate button.
- The intercolumn spacing has been removed from some of the columns, by adding a custom column declaration in the table settings. Right click a cell --> More ... --> Settings. In the *LaTeX argument* box you'll see something like `@{}r`, which creates a `r`ight aligned column with the column padding before the column removed.
- The empty braces (`{}`) before the plus signs is to ensure the right spacing. When writing `$+4$`, the plus is a unary relation, while with `${}+4$` it is a binary relation, which you want.
- I added a phantom `)` in row 1, column 2, as in [Peter Grill's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82027/586), to improve alignment.

```
#LyX 2.0 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="5" columns="4">
<features tabularvalignment="middle">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0pt" special="@{}r">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0pt" special="@{}r">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0pt" special="@{}r@{}">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0pt" special="l">
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Formula $x^{2}$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Formula ${}+4x\phantom{)}$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Formula ${}+4$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Formula ${}:x+2=x+2$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Formula $-(x^{2}$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Formula ${}+2x)$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Formula $2x$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Formula ${}+4$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Formula $2x$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Formula ${}+4$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Formula $0$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Answer (score 2):

Use table and borders. In LyX:

[image]

PDF output:

[image]

(After looking around on the web for some time, this was the easiest and nicest solution I could find. It was based on DalyaG's answer.)