# How to do long division of an angle in degrees

Tags: arithmetic, xlop, degrees

Is there a way to display the basic operations with angles in degrees, just like xlop does with integers?

For example, with integers we use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop} 
\begin{document} 
\opdiv[displayintermediary=all,voperation=top]{251}{25}
\end{document}
```

I would like to do the same with 32º33'34" : 4.

I did not find any package to do the job.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah, modulo 60 arithmetic!  Yes, it can be done, but it will be as difficult as creating xlop in the first place.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153295/long-division-of-polynomials-in-lyx for example.