# polynom division without package polynom

Tags: polynom

I am quite new to TeX, so i don't know how to represent polynom division in latex. I can't use package polynom, since I don't have a polynom with numbers so this is a generic solution for this fraction (x_1^n-x_0^n)/(x_1-x_0)

I would appreciate some help to represent this somehow like this:

[image]

A similar question was answered there: [How to draw polynom division?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79182/how-to-draw-polynom-division?newreg=37ce93fa81474e498b4769c672796e41) but i want to picture polynom division in more convinient style

[image]

like the package polynom does it and don't know how to tune that solution for my purposes

Comment: A solution with `align` and `booktabs`: [How to typeset and annotate a polynomial long division](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82027).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is using the under-development `tabstackengine` package, first introduced here at [Writing a table with equally spaced columns, based on the widest column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139771/writing-a-table-with-equally-spaced-columns-based-on-the-widest-column/139946#139946) (source code available at [Measuring align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142406/measuring-align/142608#142608)).

The package extends the `stackengine` package by adding tabbing capability.  This answer, [Can I tab inside of align environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148669/can-i-tab-inside-of-align-environment/148684#148684), gives some of the syntax of the package.  I apologize that I have been lax in completing the package and getting it out the door, so the only way to see it in action is by searching this site for `tabstackengine`.

In this particular answer, I set up the polynomial division with a tabular stack, where I set the alignments of each column.  The only twist is the introduction of the macro `\rl{}` which give a rule corresponding to the typeset contents of the mathematical argument (extended with a `llap` and `\rlap` to make smooth transitions).

The answer below has been EDITED in response to Barbara'a comment, through a redefinition of `\rl{}`.  My earlier solution artificially extended the horizontal gap between stacked columns, which was a proper criticism.  An additional criticism levied had to do with the unequal spacings around the math operators.  To a large extent, this edit corrects much of that.  However, residual asymmetries about the `-` and `+` characters are notably due to the alignment requirements of the columns.  For example, in the middle rows, there is more space prior to the `7x` than after the preceding `-x^2`.  This occurs because the `7x` must achieve right-alignment with the somewhat wider `(4x` three rows later.  In essence, `mathrel` spacings are sacrificed in order to maintain column alignments, which is considered essential to this problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\newsavebox\tempbox
\newlength\templen
\def\rl#1{%
  \sbox\tempbox{$#1$}%
  \setlength\templen{\wd\tempbox}%
  \llap{\rule{1.5pt}{.1ex}}\rule{\templen}{.1ex}\rlap{\rule{1.5pt}{.1ex}}}
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\begin{document}
\tabularShortstack{crcrcrcrl}{
 &(3x^3&-&10x^2&+&7x &-&12&): (x-3) = 3x^2 -x + 4\\
-&(3x^3&-&9x^2 &)&   & &  &\\
\rl{-}&\rl{(3x^3}&\rl{-}&\rl{-(x^2}&\rl{+}&&&&\\
 &     & &-x^2 &+&7x & &  &\\
 &     &-&(-x^2&+&3x &)&  &\\
&&\rl{-}&\rl{-(x^2}&\rl{+}&\rl{(7x}&\rl{-}&&\\
 &     &&      & &4x &-&12&\\
 &     &&      &-&(4x&-&12&)\\
&&&&\rl{+}&\rl{(7x}&\rl{-}&\rl{12}&\rl{)}\\
 &&&&&&&0&
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an example of another problem cited by the OP.  The only differences here were the need to use `\rlap` if an entry was to be allowed to cross column boundaries, and I also changed the column alignment to `l` for the polynomial entries, as opposed to `r` in the last example, which had constant coefficients.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\newsavebox\tempbox
\newlength\templen
\def\rl#1{%
  \sbox\tempbox{$#1$}%
  \setlength\templen{\wd\tempbox}%
  \llap{\rule{2.1pt}{.1ex}}\rule{\templen}{.1ex}\rlap{\rule{2.1pt}{.1ex}}}
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\begin{document}
\tabularShortstack{crllclcl}{
 &(x^n&-&x_0^n&)%
  \rlap{$:(x-x_0) =  x^{n+1} + x_0x^{n-2} + x_0^2x^{n-3} + \ldots $}&&&\\
-&(x^n&-&x_0x^{n-1} &)&   & &\\
\rl{-}&\rl{(x^n}&\rl{-(}&\rl{(x_0x^{n-1}}&\rl{+}&&&\\
 &     & &x_0x^{n-1} &-&x_0^n & &\\
 &     &-(&x_0x^{n-1}&-&x_0^2x^{n-2} &)&\\
&&\rl{-(}&\rl{(x_0x^{n-1}}&\rl{+}&\rl{x_0^2x^{n-2}}&\rl{-}&\\
 &     &&      & &x_0^2x^{n-2}&-&x_0^n\\
\rule{0ex}{3ex}&&&&&\rlap{...................}&&
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: there-s really too much space after many of the minus signs.  both operations and unary minus signs are affected.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Please see edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! I wonder though if I can put that minus sign between the lines?

Comment: @DanyloEsterman You are most welcome.  What do you mean "between the lines"?  Do you mean to shift the leading minus vertically, horizontally, or something completely different?

Comment: better.  not perfect, but i expect the extra space between minus/plus signs and a following element is an accommodation to line up with later lines that have parentheses in those locations.  still, the initial minus signs pre-parentheses should really be spaced as unary, not binary; that would compensate somewhat for the extra space inserted on account of the open parentheses.  (this is rather a tricky situation, and you may have already made the best of it.)

Comment: This is what i mean: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/546/gdbd.png

Comment: And actually the second image was only to show the style of the drawing, what i really need to draw is on the first image (x_1^n-x_0^n)/(x_1-x_0)
Trying to apply your code to my formula, but i dont really know how to deal with all these ampersands

Comment: @DanyloEsterman The ampersands are the column delimiters.  Each row should have the same number of ampersands (8), meaning a total of 9 columns (with the alignments given by `(crcrcrcrl)`.  For the `\rl{}` lines, I place the widest element of the column as the argument, if I want an underline in that column.  By the way, I was unable to look at the imagizer site, because it is blocked from me.  But if I get a chance, i will try to look at your top example.

Comment: I still cannot reach desired result. Could you post code for drawing this polynom divison http://i.stack.imgur.com/RlyJv.png please?

Comment: @DanyloEsterman The `.tex` code I use is given in the above answer.  The version of `tabstackengine` I use to create the above result is given at the end of the answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142406/measuring-align/142608#142608.  It is the piece of code that begins with the line `\def\tabstackengineversionnumber{V0.21}`.  The only other suggestion I might have is to make sure your other packages are up to date.  Packages referenced directly or indirectly include `stackengine`, `fixltx2e`, `etoolbox`, `etex`, and `calc`.

Comment: I've already got tabstackengine working, but I still can't figure it out how to draw the right polynom division. The .tex code you given above is for another problem, namely this one: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bQwaV.jpg As I already mentioned, I provided this polynom division just to make you understand how the result has too look.

Comment: Sorry if i express myself not clearly enough, english is not my mother tognue.

Comment: @DanyloEsterman Your English is quite acceptable.  I had forgotten that you had asked further assistance on the other type of problem.  See revised answer to see if it helps.