# Eqnarray vs align environments

Tags: tables, spacing, formatting, equations

I keep reading that `\begin{align}` is preferred to `\begin{eqnarray}`.

Unfortunately, I can't get `align` to justify rcl. I'll change between `align` and `eqnarray`, and the rightmost column is right justified. So, align for me looks like rcr. Does anyone know what I could be doing? I want the old rcl justification.

Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: Note that `align` uses only 1 alignment character `&=` to obtain it's regular rl alignment. `eqnarray` uses 2 alignment characters `& = &`... how are you using it?

Comment: Good descriptions in this regard can be found in »[Avoid `eqnarray`!](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2012-1/madsen.html)« and the »[Math mode](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathmode)« document.

Comment: It would help if you provided a minimum working example.  But the `tabstackengine` package (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155579/polynom-division-without-package-polynom/155609#155609) can provide `tabular` style alignments to an array.

Comment: a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) would be great- btw, welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't expect that change. The single & is what I need.