# Polylongdiv: Show x^n if the coefficient = 0

Tags: polynom

I'm trying to figure out how to display x^n with 0 as coefficient in the polynom divison. I'm using the polynom package for this but the following example doesn't show x^3 and x.

Minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\polyset{style=C,div=:,vars=x}
\polylongdiv{x^4 + 0 x^3 - 45 x^2 + 0x + 324}{x - 6}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I didn't find anything in the package's manual. So is there a solution for my problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This will not be that easy as we would have to redefine the package `polynom`. Clearly, it decides for you not to display the zero terms and I guess, it should be possible to avoid this decision. But if you just need to type such an expression (with zeros) for one time, you should have a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155609

Comment: Thx. This solved my problem :)

Comment: Good to hear. Maybe, you just post your new formula as an answer here. And if no other solutions come up the next time, you can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

As LaRiFaRi said here's my solution:

```
$\tabularShortstack{crcrcrcrcrl}{
    &(x^4       &+      &0x^3       &-          &45x^2      &+          &0x         &+      &324        &): (x-6) = x^3 + 6x^2 - 9x - 54\\
-       &(x^4       &-      &6x^3       &)          &           &           &           &\\
\rl{-}  &\rl{(x^4}  &\rl{-} &\rl{6x^3.} &\rl{)}     &           &           &           &\\
    &           &       &6x^3       &-          &45x^2      &           &           &\\
    &           &-      &(6x^3      &-          &36x^2      &)          &           &\\
    &           &\rl{-} &\rl{(6x^3} &\rl{-}     &\rl{36x^2-}&\rl{.)}    &           &\\
    &           &       &           &           &-9x^2      &+          &0x         &\\
    &           &       &           &-          &(-9x^2     &+          &54x        &)\\
    &           &       &           &\rl{-}     &\rl{(-9x^2}&\rl{+}     &\rl{54x))} &\rl{)}\\
    &           &       &           &           &           &           &           &\\
    &           &       &           &           &           &           &-54x       &+      &324\\
    &           &       &           &           &           &-(         &-54x       &+      &324        &)\\
    &           &       &           &           &           &\rl{-(}    &\rl{-54x}  &\rl{+} &\rl{324}   &\rl{)}\\
    &           &       &           &           &           &           &           &       &0
}$
```

[image]