# compose polynomial in latex

Tags: polynom

I would create such a similar thing:

[image]

I tried using `polynom` package but the operation I'm doing aren't the common operation because I'm working on galois field so I don't want the result that `polynom` package give me.
How can I create that image ?

Comment: What would you be giving as an input?

Comment: I gave \polylongdiv{}{}

Comment: I mean... Would you give only the polynomials `x^3 + x^2 + 1` and `x+1`, or the full computation, possibly with alignment characters?

Comment: I would have the full computation with alignment characters...

Comment: Then you could edit the question to make it clear. You understand that it does greatly change the nature and difficulty of the task.

Comment: @Mazzy TeX is not good in higher algebra, I'm afraid. :)

Comment: Related: [How to draw polynomial division?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79182/5764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an `array` in conjunction with [the `booktabs` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs):

[image]

### Notes:

- This example was more focused on the alignment issues and not the drawing issues, so there us probably much room for improvent related to the drawing portion.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand*{\Ph}{\hphantom{{}+{}}}%

\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{r  l@{} l@{} l@{} l@{} l@{}}
                                    &x^4 &{}+ 1  \\
\cmidrule{2-6}
\multicolumn{1}{r |}{x^3 + x^2 + 1} &x^4 &        &{}+ x^2 &{}+ x &{}+ 1 \\
                                    &x^4 &{}+ x^3 &        &{}+ x & \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
                                    &    &\Ph x^3 &{}+ x^2 &      &{}+1\\
                                    &    &\Ph x^3 &{}+ x^2 &      &{}+1\\
\cmidrule(l{10pt}){3-6}
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```