# Long division of polynoms with equivalence classes

Tags: polynom

I know of the `polynom` package for typesetting long divisions of polynoms. What I want to do is to typeset a long division of two polynoms that contain not numbers but equivalence classes based on the modulo. By that I mean that I use sets of numbers where the division with rest by a predefined number yields the same number (e.g. if this number is 3, both 4 and 7 will be in the same class [1]) instead of actual numbers.

Anyway, with a package where I enter the calculation manually what non-numbers I calculate on would not be relevant.

`polynom` can't calculate those.

Is there a package that does this, either manually or automatically like `polynom`?

Comment: TeX is a _typesetting system_. Try [sage](http://sagemath.org/) together with the `sagetex` package for LaTeX.

Comment: You don't say? I did mention that I'm perfectly fine with manually entering the actual calculations.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded rude. I don't like the idea behind packages like `polynom`. I know you mentioned you're ok with manually entering, but I don't know any package to help you with that. On the other hand, I thought that mentioning `sagetex` at this place can be helpful.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84562/14100

Comment: I don't understand the question. The nearest I can guess is that you want to present long divisions with results modulo some ideal. (This doesn't make sense to me.) Can you provide an example/be more precise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no such package. Maybe a reworking of `polynom` might allow this, but it seems to be very extensive work.