# Long division between two polynomials, one has a variable coefficient

Tags: polynomials

I would like to do the long division between polynomials `p(x)=-x^4+2x^2-(a-1)^2x+1` (where `a` is a real number) and `q(x)=x+1`:

[image: Sketch of long division]

I tried to use `polynom` package as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}

\polylongdiv[style=D,vars=x]{-x^4+2x^2-(a-1)^2x+1}{x+1}

\end{document}
```

without results.

**EDIT.** I tried to expand `(a-1)^2` but errors seem to appear. Also, I changed `(a-1)(a-1)` by `(a-1)(a+1)` and LaTeX goes a little crazy but with no errors:

[image: Example]

Does anyone know any trick to make it work or a package that allows the insertion of variables?

Comment: Have a look at my answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79182/how-to-draw-polynom-division?newreg=37ce93fa81474e498b4769c672796e41

Comment: @BlackMild thank you! It seems a bit lazy to do but in the end the division can be achieved.